# How do I get MongoDB version via SELECT query to Linked Server?

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, select, version

In Sql Server I have several Linked Servers and trying to get their Server version using say

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyLinkedServer, 'SELECT VERSION();')
```

which works fine for PostgreSQL and MySQL, **but not for MongoDB**.

Before anyone says that MongoDB is not a SQL-like database, I would point out that

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyMongoDB, 'SELECT NOW() As A, 1 * 2 + 3 AS B')
```

returns A as date+time and B as 5, as expected, because the ODBC connection SQL-ifies MongoDB

Comment: which driver do you use to query your `MyMongoDB`-server?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Linked Server property gives 'Microsoft OLE DB provider for ODBC Drivers',
I do not have access to the SQL Server itself, just via SSMS, so no direct access to ODBC Data Source.
Asking around, it seems to be via the EasySoft ODBC driver

Comment: Have you checked the features of [MongoDB ODBC Driver](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-mongodb-driver) - is `Version()` supported?